# Cloudflare (and other DNS based CDNs) - caching with Auth

Tags: caching, cdn, cloudflare

We have a test server that has HTTP authentication.

Cloudflare is being used to do CDN caching.

The test server has got authentication to avoid it being indexed by Google (as the robots.txt file occasionally got deleted!).

Will Cloudflare be able to cache content if we have authentication on this server?

If so, how is it doing it? I thought the content would be transmitted directly between the server and the browser.

Comment: CF should pass the authentication along, and cache the static resources.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on cloudflare CDN. But let me tell you in general how this works or how it works in Akamai.

If you have an authentication protected website say https://secure.test.com/admin

so when the request is sent to CDN. CDN will check if the incoming request has a token(Cookie) that it can understand. If not then it will send the request to your origin server. But before doing that it will append something like /token.php?return=/admin

Now origin server will authenticate the user. once done it will execute token.php in origin server, which will generate a unique encrypted token along with other application cookies. Basically the key that you use in this token.php for encryption cookie generation will be the same that you add in your CDN config.

So next request that comes in for /admin will have a cdn token which cdn will verify for authenticity using the key that you have in CDN config(Same as that of origin). If successful it will server the content from its cache.

Note: Make sure that the CDN token expiry is less than the application cookies.
Say your application session cookie is for 8 hours then its best to set cdn cookie to 1 hour or so. By this CDN will contact your origin once in a hour and get its token renewed. Hope i didn't make it more confusing ;-)

Comment: Re `append something like /token.php?return=/admin`, do you mean to the URL? Or the cookie? If it's the URL then doesn't this risk breaking the web application. If it's the cookie then I'd use the same logic.

Comment: And I'm not clear what you mean by `execute token.php in origin server`. Surely this file won't exist on the origin server.

Comment: Hello, well token.php was just an example, this could be of any other programming version file too. Usually this file is provided by the CDN provider. Basically this file will generate a cookie after user is authenticated in origin and sets cookie in user browser, so that next time when the browser makes the request, the CDN knows that this is a authentic user.

Comment: all this token.php in my example does it after authentication when /token.php?return=/admin is requested from origin, origin server will hit the php file which will generate the cookie and then the redirect is done from /token.php?return=/admin to /admin which was your original request.